# Defining part of a mock call as default values

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, mocking, response

I'm writing a unittest to ensure a mocked method is called with the correct arguments.

Part of my unittest looks like this:

```
response = MagicMock(name='response', status_code=200)

# Make some calls

expected_calls = [
    call(
        "X",
        "1",
        domain="mywebsite.com",
        httponly=True,
        max_age=1000,
        path="/",
        secure=False,
    ),
    call(
        "Y",
        "2",
        domain="mywebsite.com",
        httponly=True,
        max_age=1000,
        path="/",
        secure=False,
    ),
]
response.set_cookie.assert_has_calls(expected_calls)
```

In other words, only the key and value of these call objects changes.

How can I get something of the form:

```
default_values = {...}

expected_calls = [
    call(
        "X",
        "1",
        default_values,
        ),
    call(
        "Y",
        "2",
        default_values,
    ),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, perhaps you didn't know that you can star unpack you `default_values` dict. A simple example at Python console is below:

```
>>> d1 = dict(a=1, b=2)
>>> from unittest.mock import call
>>> call(1, 10, **d1)
call(1, 10, a=1, b=2)
>>>
```

where `d1` would be your `default_values`.

This is possible since Python 3.5 as per [PEP448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)